# Changing the background color for a specific page using Next JS

Tags: css, next.js

I am creating a project using Next Js and recently I have run into a problem with my project as I have already created a global.css in it and I am trying to change the color of the background of only one specific page in it by going over the attributes set by the global.css since I already tried to change the background using the Chakra UI but you can still see the background set by the global.css underneath.

Is it possible to do this?

I am also using Chakra UI, and try to change the background using it. But you can still see the background stablished by the global.css underneath.

Comment: It's hard to give you a straight answer without seeing your code. You can import another css file or use css modules.

Comment: Create a app file (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app). surround the components by a div & set a class on the div according to the route.  use the class to set the bg image.

Answer (score 0):

1. create an _app file as described here (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app)
2. Detect which page you are on using the Next/Router (https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#userouter)
3. Create a wrapper and set the class based on page route.
4. Create CSS to set the bg accordingly.

Your _app should look something like this.

```
    const {asPath} = useRouter();
        

    const Page = asPath == '/' ? 'home-page' : '';
        

    return (
                <div className={Page}>
                    <Component {...pageProps} />
                </div>
            );
```

Hope this helps

Cheers!

Comment: By doing it this way all the pages are modified... Is there another solution? Or maybe any way to do this directly in global css?

Comment: You still need some targeting conditions in the CSS to discriminate one page from another.